# How to force focus after set data - VueJS

Tags: vue.js, autocomplete

Why i can't set focus() into this autoComplete after v-on:changeSelect fired?

```
  <auto-complete 
   p-id="txtUf" 
   p-title="UF" 
   ref="comobUf"
   :p-service-url="rotas.rotaComboUF"
   v-model="endereco.uf"
   p-value="_id"
   p-label="sigla"
   v-on:changeSelect="setUF"
   class="col s12 m2 l1">
  </auto-complete>
```

`setUF: function(e: IEstado) {
      Vue.set(this.endereco, "uf", e);
      this.rotas.rotaComboMunicipio = (<any>this).$root.routes._("municipio.find") + e._id;
    }`

Already tried to reach with $refs and $el but my cursor always go to the url field.

Comment: Did you try `$event`? Need jsfiddle or codepen

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved with the following code:

```
v-on:keyup.tab="setFocus($event)"

setFocus: function(event) {
      if (event) {
        event.focus();
      }
```